# How to add image links in canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>Image to use:</p>
<img id="scream" src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/img_the_scream.jpg" alt="The Scream" width="220" height="277">
<img id="scream1" src="http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png" alt="The Scream" width="50" height="20">
<p>Canvas to fill:</p>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="250" height="300"
style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<p><button onclick="myCanvas()">Try it</button></p>

<script>
function myCanvas() {
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var img = document.getElementById("scream");
    ctx.drawImage(img,10,10);

 var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var img = document.getElementById("scream1");
    ctx.drawImage(img,50,80);

var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var img = document.getElementById("scream1");
    ctx.drawImage(img,150,150);

var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var img = document.getElementById("scream1");
    ctx.drawImage(img,180,120);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

How to add image links in canvas . How can I add navigation in map marker images which loaded in canvas? Is it possible to add  tag for images and to get tooltip ?

Answer (score 0):

`canvas` is a single element and therefore does not support the tooltips or separate element views - for canvas, everything is but a pixel. So you can trace mouse events by creating your own wrapper around canvas and using some built-in methods to see what part of the image you are hovering over, but thats about it.

Now first off your script is doing the same thing *over and over*, you just need to get your canvas element and context once, as well as getting your images only once.

```
function myCanvas() {

    var canvas, context, image1, image2;

    image1 = document.getElementById("scream");
    image2 = document.getElementById("scream1");

    canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    context.drawImage(image1,10,10);
    context.drawImage(image2,50,80);
    context.drawImage(image2,150,150);
    context.drawImage(image1,180,120);
}
```

Now, to detect where your mouse is hovering you need to detect what your image sizes are check if the mouse is hovering inside the region. I will doing it for only one image, but you get the gist. This code would need to be  optimised to allow for an arbitrary amount of images, but for now it will work:

```
function addEventListenersToCanvas(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event){
        var image = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        if(
            event.clientX > 10 && event.clientX < 10 + image.width &&
            event.clientY > 10 && event.clientY < 10 + image.height
        ){
            console.log('hovering on image 1');
        }
    });
}
```

Now to optimise this, I would actually detect the image yourself and autmate the code. The combo would look like the following code, but keep in mind that I had to make a lot of adjustments to allow for your variable placements. Now you will have to redraw your canvas every frame to show the effect of hovering, which will complicate your code a bit more. To be honest, it seems that the DOM is a better solution for this than using canvas.

```js
var images = [];

function myCanvas() {

  var canvas, context, image1, image2;

  image1 = document.getElementById("scream");
  image2 = document.getElementById("scream1");

  canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  context = canvas.getContext("2d");

  context.drawImage(image1,10,10);
  // We oush every image to an array because otherwise
  // we wont be able to save the x and y values you set here,
  // and our event for loop would not work.
  images.push({x:10,y:10,img:image1});

  context.drawImage(image2,50,80);
  images.push({x:50,y:80,img:image2});

  context.drawImage(image1,150,150);
  images.push({x:150,y:150,img:image1});

  context.drawImage(image2,180,120);
  images.push({x:180,y:120,img:image2});

}

function addEventListenersToCanvas(canvas){
  var canvas = canvas || document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event){
    for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++){
      if(
        event.clientX > images[i].x && event.clientX < images[i].x + images[i].img.width &&
        event.clientY > images[i].y && event.clientY < images[i].y + images[i].img.height
      ){
        console.log('hovering on: ' + images[i].img.getAttribute('id'));
      }
    }
    
  });
}

myCanvas();
addEventListenersToCanvas();
```

```html
<p>Image to use:</p>

<img id="scream" src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/img_the_scream.jpg" alt="The Scream" width="220" height="277">

<img id="scream1" src="http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png" alt="The Scream" width="50" height="20">

<p>Canvas to fill:</p>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="250" height="300"
style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
```